# Can I use factory girl for non persistent models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :poem do
    skip_create
    title "Poem title"
    intro_verse
    trait_verse
    message_verse
  end
end
```

for the following non active record model class:

```
class Poem
  attr_accessor :title, :intro_verse, :trait_verse, :message_verse
end
```

Can I create a factory for such a class?

When I run the following test:

```
it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(build(:poem)).to be_valid
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(build(:poem)).to be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `valid?'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because the class does not have an instance method `valid?`. (Active Record models have this defined by default)

You need to come up with some logic for determining whether a Poem instance is valid or not, and write a `valid?` method accordingly.

IIRC, the syntax `expect(something).to be_condition` simply calls the method `condition?` on `something` and fails if it returns false.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the clarification. Would `expect(build(:poem)).to be_a Poem` be a useful test? I mean, could this test possibly fail if something goes wrong?

Comment: why not implement a `valid?` method that checks to see whether the required attributes have been set?

Comment: Yep, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: You could include `ActiveModel::Validations` in your class, which would give you the `valid?` method, and allow you to specify validations easliy.  See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations for more details, and examples using non-persisted classes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ActiveModel::Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#validations) module to adds the ability to validate class objects like in Active Record:

```
class Poem
    include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :title, presence: true
  attr_accessor :title, :intro_verse, :trait_verse, :message_verse
end

poem = Poem.new
poem.valid? #false
poem.title = "title"
poem.valid? #true
```